# How To Correctly Determine UI Image Size For Larger IPhones

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface-builder

I am slightly confused when it comes to creating images for the IPhone 6 and 6 plus. The problem is I have a button created using IB set at say 70x70. I want the button to expand so that it increases for the larger IPhones

Now if I test this out by switching between size options in IB I notice the size changes as expected so:

4 Inch = 70x70
4.7 Inch = 83x85
5.5 Inch = 91x96

I was wondering in terms of creating the assets i.e @2x and @3x do I do it based upon the 70x70 or do I go by the largest size so 91x96? I know the aspect ratio stays the same so I am a little unsure as to what to pick.

Comment: Create 2x and 3x assets based on the original point size (your 70 x 70 image). Then let iOS select the correct image at run time. The size of your button should be set using Autolayout.

Comment: Thats what I was wondering, my default UIView I work from in Xcode is the 4 Inch. If I create the button design using 70 x 70 wont the btn image look distorted though on the IPhone 6 because wouldn't it be @3 x (91x96)?

Comment: Your button should always be 70 points by 70 points. This means a 1x image is 70 pixels by 70 pixels, a 2x image is 140 pixels by 140 pixels and a 3x images is 210 pixels by 210 pixels. You should ignore your calculations based on the physical width of the screen as this does not have a linear relationship with the screen points (or rendered pixels or physical pixels). This is covered in the iOS HIG (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) and other places on the web (e.g. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

Answer (score 0):

I would not change the image sizes around.

Instead, lets constraint your imageView right, and leave the @2x, @3x as it is.